# How to get more one values of variable?

Tags: php, android, json, if-statement, switch-statement

A long time ago there was an example parsing data in android with json.

.java

```
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String TAG_DAFTAR_RS = "daftar_rs";
public static final String TAG_ID_RS = "id_rs";
public static final String TAG_NAMA_RS = "nama_rs";
public static final String TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS = "link_image_rs";
public static final String TAG_ALAMAT_RS = "alamat_rs";
public static final String TAG_TELEPON_RS = "telepon_rs";
```

.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, nama, link_image, alamat, telepon FROM tbl_rumah_sakit ORDER BY nama ASC  ") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$response["daftar_rs"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $daftar_rs = array();
    $daftar_rs["id_rs"] = $row["id"];
    $daftar_rs["nama_rs"] = stripslashes($row["nama"]);
    $daftar_rs["link_image_rs"] = stripslashes($row["link_image"]);
    $daftar_rs["alamat_rs"] = stripslashes($row["alamat"]);
    $daftar_rs["telepon_rs"] = stripslashes($row["telepon"]);
    array_push($response["daftar_rs"], $daftar_rs);
}

$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
} else {

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "error";

echo json_encode($response);
}
```

It worked cool and everyone was happy. But in one day, one boy like hobbit, decided to change this example, because he has his own task. And of course he destroyed everything.
What he did? He did

```
    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String TAG_LIST = "list_k";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id_k";
    public static String TAG_TEXT_NAME;
    public static String TAG_LINK_IMAGE;
```

values of TAG_TEXT_NAME and TAG_LINK_IMAGE he gets from another activity by button putExtra. Variables can have values "text1","text2","text3" and "image1","image2","image3" it depends on clicking a button1,button2 or button3.
So he must change and php script too, and he changed it too.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_rumah_sakit ORDER BY id ASC  ") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


$response["list_k"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text1"] = stripslashes($row["text1"]);
$list_k["image1"] = stripslashes($row["image1"]);

$list_k["text2"] = stripslashes($row["text2"]);
$list_k["image2"] = stripslashes($row["image2"]);

    $list_k["text3"] = stripslashes($row["text3"]);
$list_k["image3"] = stripslashes($row["image3"]);
array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
}

$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
} else {

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "error";

echo json_encode($response);
}
```

He hoped that it will work but he got trouble.It worked only for text1, and image1. He was very unhappy. But he not hands down. He'd modified it like this

```
switch(true){
case "text1":
    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text1"] = stripslashes($row["text1"]);
$list_k["image1"] = stripslashes($row["image1"]);
array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
break;
case "text2":
    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text2"] = stripslashes($row["text2"]);
$list_k["image2"] = stripslashes($row["image2"]);
    array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
break;
case "text3":
    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text3"] = stripslashes($row["text3"]);
$list_k["image3"] = stripslashes($row["image3"]);
    array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
break;
default: echo"You didn't give me a value how I can work? Please, give me text1 or text2 or text3";
}
```

But it worked for only first value (text1). His disappointment was deep. But he don't hands down. He changed his php script to this

```
if('text1'){   
    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text1"] = stripslashes($row["text1"]);
$list_k["image1"] = stripslashes($row["image1"]);
    array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
}else if('text2'){
    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text2"] = stripslashes($row["text2"]);
$list_k["image2"] = stripslashes($row["image2"]);
    array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
}else if("text3"){
    $list_k = array();
$list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
$list_k["text3"] = stripslashes($row["text3"]);
$list_k["image3"] = stripslashes($row["image3"]); 
    array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
}
```

But his app crashed again and again. Please, if you are seeing this post, and if you can help, do not ignore him. He is very glorios boy.
Logcat

```
02-25 08:55:24.920: W/System.err(2822):     org.json.JSONException: No value for text2(text3 give the same logcat error)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at com.example.testtaskmyapp.MainActivity$Activity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:158)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at com.example.testtaskmyapp.MainActivity$Activity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
02-25 08:55:24.930: W/System.err(2822):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-25 08:55:24.940: W/System.err(2822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-25 08:55:24.940: W/System.err(2822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-25 08:55:24.940: W/System.err(2822):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: I believe he is getting most famous `NullPointerException` after modifying code.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Why he is getting NullPointerException?

Comment: when click button1 text1,image1 works cool. When he clicks button2 logcat says no value for text1 and by clicking button3, logcat says no value for text3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your first  variant, check, it must works(not optimal but it must works)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $list_k = array();
  $list_k["id_k"] = $row["id"];
    $list_k["text1"] = stripslashes($row["text1"]);
    $list_k["image1"] = stripslashes($row["image1"]);

    $list_k["text2"] = stripslashes($row["text2"]);
    $list_k["image2"] = stripslashes($row["image2"]);

    $list_k["text3"] = stripslashes($row["text3"]);
    $list_k["image3"] = stripslashes($row["image3"]);
  array_push($response["list_k"], $list_k);
}
```